# How do I specify a publisher for the setup.exe when a setup CD is autoplayed in Windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cd, autoplay

I have a setup CD to install a visual studio C++ application I made.  The AutoPlay popup shows "Publisher not specified" for running setup.exe.  How do I specify a publisher?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to [Sign the executable with a digital certificate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_signing). This is to verify that the executable has not been tampered with and is from the publisher.